# iOS / Swift can not natively decompress a group of files which are .zip. Is there another format, which ios/Swift will do so?

Tags: ios, swift, compression, file-handling

I want to

- decompress say 5 or 10 files, which have been zipped **specifically to one file** (although this is not possible with a .zip file, the nature of the question, so it has to be **some other format** which iOS handles natively)
- I do *not* want to use any third party libraries such as SSZipArchive, WPZipArchive etc.

Note that Quinn from Apple clearly explains here that .zip is not possible: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694893

It would appear that iOS/Swift has, built in, support for

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_and_decompressing_files_with_stream_compression-ke6

however I have no clue how to deal with a folder of files.

Thus, the folder of files, abc.something, would be just local to the iOS app.  (Or, trivially, I could say download them from the net etc beforehand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Apple Archive Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applearchive) supports what you're looking for.